# Can named arguments be used with Python enums?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, named-parameters

Example:

```
class Planet(Enum):

    MERCURY = (mass: 3.303e+23, radius: 2.4397e6)

    def __init__(self, mass, radius):
        self.mass = mass       # in kilograms
        self.radius = radius   # in meters
```

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#planet

Why do I want to do this?  If there are a few primitive types (int, bool) in the constructor list, it would be nice to used named arguments.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

While you can't use named arguments the way you describe with enums, you can get a similar effect with a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) mixin:

```
from collections import namedtuple
from enum import Enum

Body = namedtuple("Body", ["mass", "radius"])

class Planet(Body, Enum):

    MERCURY = Body(mass=3.303e+23, radius=2.4397e6)
    VENUS   = Body(mass=4.869e+24, radius=6.0518e6)
    EARTH   = Body(mass=5.976e+24, radius=3.3972e6)
    # ... etc.
```

... which to my mind is cleaner, since you don't have to write an `__init__` method.

Example use:

```
>>> Planet.MERCURY
<Planet.MERCURY: Body(mass=3.303e+23, radius=2439700.0)>
>>> Planet.EARTH.mass
5.976e+24
>>> Planet.VENUS.radius
6051800.0
```

Note that, as per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#others), "mix-in types must appear before `Enum` itself in the sequence of bases".

Comment: Very cool.  I never considered solving the problem with a mixin.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus:  I added an answer, but not for the bounty -- just hoping for some up-votes (long way to go for my [python-3.x] gold badge! ;) .

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer by @zero-piraeus can be slightly extended to allow default arguments as well.  This is very handy when you have a large enum with most entries having the same value for an element.

```
class Body(namedtuple('Body', "mass radius moons")):
    def __new__(cls, mass, radius, moons=0):
        return super().__new__(cls, mass, radius, moons)
    def __getnewargs__(self):
        return (self.mass, self.radius, self.moons)

class Planet(Body, Enum):

    MERCURY = Body(mass=3.303e+23, radius=2.4397e6)
    VENUS   = Body(mass=4.869e+24, radius=6.0518e6)
    EARTH   = Body(5.976e+24, 3.3972e6, moons=1)
```

Beware pickling will not work without the `__getnewargs__`.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.planet = Planet.EARTH  # pickle error in deepcopy

from copy import deepcopy

f1 = Foo()
f2 = deepcopy(f1)  # pickle error here
```

Answer (score 12):

For Python 3.6.1+ the [typing.NamedTuple](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) can be used, which also allows for setting default values, which leads to prettier code. The example by @shao.lo then looks like this:

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import NamedTuple


class Body(NamedTuple):
    mass: float
    radius: float
    moons: int=0


class Planet(Body, Enum):
    MERCURY = Body(mass=3.303e+23, radius=2.4397e6)
    VENUS   = Body(mass=4.869e+24, radius=6.0518e6)
    EARTH   = Body(5.976e+24, 3.3972e6, moons=1)
```

This also supports pickling. The typing.Any can be used if you don't want to specify the type.

Credit to @monk-time, who's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43157792/5693369) inspired this solution.

Answer (score 6):

If going beyond the `namedtuple` mix-in check out the [`aenum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) library<sup>1</sup>.  Besides having a few extra bells and whistles for `Enum` it also supports `NamedConstant` and a metaclass-based `NamedTuple`.

Using `aenum.Enum` the above code could look like:

```
from aenum import Enum, enum, _reduce_ex_by_name

class Planet(Enum, init='mass radius'):
    MERCURY = enum(mass=3.303e+23, radius=2.4397e6)
    VENUS   = enum(mass=4.869e+24, radius=6.0518e6)
    EARTH   = enum(mass=5.976e+24, radius=3.3972e6)
    # replace __reduce_ex__ so pickling works
    __reduce_ex__ = _reduce_ex_by_name
```

and in use:

```
--> for p in Planet:
...     print(repr(p))
<Planet.MERCURY: enum(radius=2439700.0, mass=3.3030000000000001e+23)>
<Planet.EARTH: enum(radius=3397200.0, mass=5.9760000000000004e+24)>
<Planet.VENUS: enum(radius=6051800.0, mass=4.8690000000000001e+24)>

--> print(Planet.VENUS.mass)
4.869e+24
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.