# Why should I use the __prepare__ method to get a class' namespace?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

**Note** *This question is not about the Python 3 `Enum` data type, it's just the example I'm using.*

With [PEP 3115](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/) Python 3 added the [`__prepare__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#preparing-the-class-namespace)<sup>1</sup> method to `type` for the purpose of allowing a custom namespace to be used when creating classes.  For example, the new `Enum` data type uses `__prepare__` to return an instance of the private `_EnumDict` for use as the new `Enum` class' namespace.

However, I have seen several examples on SO<sup>2</sup> of `EnumMeta` being subclassed, creating a new namespace for the class in the metaclass `__new__` method, but instead of calling the `__prepare__` method to acquire that new namespace, `type(clsdict)()` is used instead.  Are there any risks to doing it this way?

---

<sup>1</sup>  The signature for `__prepare__`:

```
@classmethod
def __prepare__(metacls, cls, bases, **kwds):
```

and for `__new__`:

```
def __new__(metacls, cls, bases, clsdict, **kwds):
```

---

<sup>2</sup>  Example using `type(clsdict)`:

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43100224/208880)

```
class CountryCodeMeta(enum.EnumMeta):
    def __new__(metacls, cls, bases, classdict):
        data = classdict['data']
        names = [(country['alpha-2'], int(country['country-code'])) for country in data]

  -->   temp = type(classdict)()
        for name, value in names:
            temp[name] = value

        excluded = set(temp) | set(('data',))
        temp.update(item for item in classdict.items() if item[0] not in excluded)

        return super(CountryCodeMeta, metacls).__new__(metacls, cls, bases, temp)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there are risks.

At least two reasons exist for getting the new namespace by calling `__prepare__` instead of doing `type(clsdict)()`:

- When running on Python 2 `clsdict` is a `dict`, and the original `__prepare__` never ran to begin with (`__prepare__` is Python 3 only) -- in other words, if `__prepare__` is returning something besides a normal dict, `type(clsdict)()` is not going to get it.
- Any attributes set by `__prepare__` on the `clsdict` would not be set when using `type(clsdict)()`; i.e. if `__prepare__` does `clsdict.spam = 'eggs'` then `type(clsdict)()` will not have a `spam` attribute.  Note that these attributes are on the namespace itself for use by the metaclass and are not visible in the namespace.

To summarize: there are good reasons to use `__prepare__()` to obtain the proper class dictionary, and none for the `type(clsdict)()` shortcut.