# Is it possible to override a method in a namedtuple in Python?

Tags: python, overriding, namedtuple

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
class Foo(namedtuple('Foo', ['f1'])):
    def f1(self):
        print('Default f1')

    def __new__(cls, f1=f1):
        return super().__new__(cls, f1)
```

And let's say I create a Foo object later on and choose to override the method definition for f1, like so:

```
def my_f1():
    print("My f1")

foo = Foo(f1=my_f1)
```

If I then try:

```
foo.f1()
```

I get:

```
Default f1
```

I'm trying to get "My f1" to print, of course. I also want f1 to be optional. What's going on here? Is it possible to define a default implementation for a method in a namedtuple and then override it in **new**?

Comment: It seems to me you want a namedtuple with a default value for a field. In this case, the default value is a callable, but it doesn't make much difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351032/named-tuple-and-optional-keyword-arguments

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: it makes a huge difference because the property handling the attribute is clobbered by the method.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: it makes a difference only if you want to declare `f1` inside `class Foo`. But this overly complicates things (see your own answer for the details :P). Declaring `f1` outside `class Foo` and setting it as a default argument makes things much easier.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: but the OP is expecting `foo.f1()` to work, from the `f1` argument when creating the instance. It doesn't matter if `self[0]` is a default `None` or a default external function..

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm not sure I've understood your last comment. BTW, I posted an answer.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: right, setting a function as a default works too, just different.

Answer (score 5):

You can't have both a method and a slot use the same name. Named tuples use [slots](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots), and these are implemented as `property` objects *in the same namespace as methods*. By defining a method `f1` you clobbered the `f1` property:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> namedtuple('Foo', ['f1']).f1
<property object at 0x1069764c8>
>>> class Foo(namedtuple('Foo', ['f1'])):
...     def f1(self):
...         print('Default f1')
... 
>>> Foo.f1
<unbound method Foo.f1>
```

The `property` object simply returns `self[0]`. So either access the `f1` value by position:

```
class Foo(namedtuple('Foo', ['f1'])):
    def f1(self):
        if self[0]:
            return self[0]()
        print('Default f1')
```

or give your attribute a *different* name, and have the `f1` method delegate to that:

```
class Foo(namedtuple('Foo', ['f1_callable'])):
    def f1(self):
        if self.f1_callable:
            return self.f1_callable()
        print('Default f1')
```

Demo:

```
>>> def my_f1():
...     print("My f1")
... 
>>> class Foo(namedtuple('Foo', ['f1'])):
...     def f1(self):
...         if self[0]:
...             return self[0]()
...         print('Default f1')
... 
>>> foo = Foo(my_f1)
>>> foo.f1()
My f1
>>> foo = Foo(None)
>>> foo.f1()
Default f1
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid declaring `f1` inside `class Foo`. Instead, declare it at module level, and use it as a [default argument for your namedtuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351032/named-tuple-and-optional-keyword-arguments):

```
def f1():
    print('Default f1')

Foo = namedtuple('Foo', 'f1')
Foo.__new__.__defaults__ = (f1,)
```

Usage:

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.f1()
Default f1

>>> def other_f1():
...     print('Another f1')
>>> foo = Foo(f1=other_f1)
>>> foo.f1()
Another f1
```