# Mutable default argument for a Python namedtuple

Tags: python, namedtuple

I came across a neat way of having namedtuples use default arguments from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18348004/2529619).

```
from collections import namedtuple
Node = namedtuple('Node', 'val left right')
Node.__new__.__defaults__ = (None, None, None)
Node()
```

> Node(val=None, left=None, right=None)

What would you do if you would want the default value for 'right' to be a empty list? As you may know, using a mutable default argument such as a list is a no no.

Is there a simple way to implement this?

Comment: Why are you asking for something which you yourself say is a no-no?

Comment: @John Zwinck: Can we modify __new__() so that it will change a 'None' into a new [] like we do with user defined classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that that way, because the values in `__defaults__` are the actual default values.  That is, if you wrote a function that did had `someargument=None`, and then checked inside the function body with `someargument = [] if someargument is None else someargument` or the like, the corresponding `__defaults__` entry would still be None.  In other words, you can do that with a function because in a function you can write code to do whatever you want, but you can't write custom code inside a namedtuple.

But if you want default values, just make a function that has that logic and then creates the right namedtuple:

```
def makeNode(val=None, left=None, right=None):
    if right is None:
        val = []
    return Node(val, left, right)
```

Comment: the downside of this solution is one has to know- or to remember- to actually use the factory function rather than the `Node` class. this kind of design choice isn't always obvoius.

Answer (score 3):

The way given in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34148071/2437514) works great. The only downside I see is that one has to both *know* (in the case of some other user) and *remember* to use the factory function instead of the named tuple class- both when creating the object, and when doing things like this:

```
isinstance(node, Node) #  success
isinstance(node, makeNode) #  misery
```

A way around this problem might be to do something like what is shown below.

```
NodeBase = nt('NodeBase', 'val left right')
NodeBase.__new__.__defaults__ = (None, None, None)

class Node(NodeBase):
    '''A namedtuple defined as:

    Node(val, left, right)

    with default values of (None, None, [])'''
    __slots__ = ()
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            if obj.right is None:
                obj = obj._replace(right = [])
            return obj
```

Answer (score 3):

Since this question has been asked, the [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) module has been proposed and accepted into Python.  This module has a lot of overlapping use cases with `namedtuples` but with some more flexibility and power.  In particular, you can specify a factory function for when you want to specify a default for a mutable field.

```
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Node:
    val: str
    left: List["Node"] = field(default_factory=list)
    right: List["Node"] = field(default_factory=list)
```

In a data class you specify the types of the various fields, so in this case I had to fill in a few blanks and assume that `val` would be a string and that `left` and `right` would both be lists of other `Node` objects.

Since `right` and `left` are the left hand side of an assignment in the class definition, they are optional arguments when we initialize a `Node` object.  Further, we could supply a default value, but instead we supplied a default factory, which is a function that is called with 0 arguments whenever we initialize a `Node` object without specifying those fields.

For example:

```
node_1 = Node('foo')
# Node(val='foo', left=[], right=[])

node_2 = Node('bar', left=[node_1])
# Node(val='bar', left=[Node(val='foo', left=[], right=[])], right=[])

node_3 = Node('baz')
# Node(val='baz', left=[], right=[])

node_4 = Node('quux', left=[node_2], right=[node_3])
# Node(val='quux', left=[Node(val='bar', left=[Node(val='foo', left=[], right=[])], right=[])], right=[Node(val='baz', left=[], right=[])])
```

Personally I find myself reaching for `dataclasses` over `namedtuples` for any application where I need more than just the thinnest container for data.

Answer (score -1):

Just small change in implementation from Rick Teachey, the default value can be set outside class:

```
NodeBase = namedtuple('NodeBase', 'val left right')

class Node(NodeBase):
    __slots__ = ()
    def __new__(cls, *, right=[], **kwargs):
        obj = super().__new__(cls, right=right, **kwargs)
        return obj

#IMPLEMENTATION
kw = {'val': 1, 'left':12}

m  = Node(**kw) 
# outputs Node(val=1, left=12, right=[])
```

Comment: With this code `Node(val=1, left=12, right=1)` produces `Node(val=1, left=12, right=[])`