# typing.NamedTuple and mutable default arguments

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, namedtuple

Given I want to properly using type annotations for named tuples from the typing module:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple, List

class Foo(NamedTuple):
    my_list: List[int] = []

foo1 = Foo()
foo1.my_list.append(42)

foo2 = Foo()
print(foo2.my_list)  # prints [42]
```

What is the best or cleanest ways to avoid the mutable default value misery in Python? I have a few ideas, but nothing really seems to be good

1. Using `None` as default

   ```py
   class Foo(NamedTuple):
       my_list: Optional[List[int]] = None

   foo1 = Foo()
   if foo1.my_list is None
     foo1 = foo1._replace(my_list=[])  # super ugly
   foo1.my_list.append(42)
   ```
2. Overwriting `__new__` or `__init__` won't work:

   ```
   AttributeError: Cannot overwrite NamedTuple attribute __init__
   AttributeError: Cannot overwrite NamedTuple attribute __new__
   ```
3. Special `@classmethod`

   ```
   class Foo(NamedTuple):
       my_list: List[int] = []

       @classmethod
       def use_me_instead(cls, my_list=None):
          if not my_list:
              my_list = []
          return cls(my_list)

   foo1 = Foo.use_me_instead()
   foo1.my_list.append(42)  # works!
   ```
4. Maybe using `frozenset` and avoid mutable attributes altogether? But that won't work with `Dict`s as there are no `frozendict`s.

Does anyone have a good answer?

Comment: Have you considered using a dataclass instead? That allows you to specify a default factory, rather than a default value, for a field.

Comment: @chepner, I think you can make this a proper answer. Seems that you really don't want to have mutable containers as attributes of typing.NamedTuple

Comment: I have a very loose feeling that I can't articulate well that a named tuple probably shouldn't *have* default values for its elements.

Comment: FWIW I don't really see anything wrong with the `classmethod` solution you propose in your question, which is probably what I'd go with — though I'd take out the default value in the main body of the class, so that the default can *only* be achieved via the `classmethod`.

Comment: @AlexWaygood the `classmethod` approach is dangerous  in my opinion, as we leave the standard way of instantiating Foo still buggy. But I can see your point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Blending my approach with Sebastian Wagner's [idea of using a decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68682382/13990016), we can achieve something like this:

```
from typing import NamedTuple, List, Callable, TypeVar, Type, Any, cast
from functools import wraps

T = TypeVar('T')

def default_factory(**factory_kw: Callable[[], Any]) -> Callable[[Type[T]], Type[T]]:
    def wrapper(wcls: Type[T], /) -> Type[T]:
        @wraps(wcls.__new__)
        def __new__(cls: Type[T], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> T:
            for key, factory in factory_kw.items():
                kwargs.setdefault(key, factory())
            new = super(cls, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs) # type: ignore[misc]
            # This call to cast() is necessary if you run MyPy with the --strict argument
            return cast(T, new)
        cls_name = wcls.__name__
        wcls.__name__ = wcls.__qualname__ = f'_{cls_name}'
        return type(cls_name, (wcls, ), {'__new__': __new__, '__slots__': ()})
    return wrapper

@default_factory(my_list=list)
class Foo(NamedTuple):
    # You do not *need* to have the default value in the class body,
    # but it makes MyPy a lot happier
    my_list: List[int] = [] 
    
foo1 = Foo()
foo1.my_list.append(42)

foo2 = Foo()
print(f'foo1 list: {foo1.my_list}')     # prints [42]
print(f'foo2 list: {foo2.my_list}')     # prints []
print(Foo)                              # prints <class '__main__.Foo'>
print(Foo.__mro__)                      # prints (<class '__main__.Foo'>, <class '__main__._Foo'>, <class 'tuple'>, <class 'object'>)
from inspect import signature
print(signature(Foo.__new__))           # prints (_cls, my_list: List[int] = [])
```

Run it through MyPy, and MyPy informs us that the revealed type of `foo1` and `foo2` is still `"Tuple[builtins.list[builtins.int], fallback=__main__.Foo]"`

Original answer below.

---

How about this? (Inspired by [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45046653/13990016)):

```
from typing import NamedTuple, List, Optional, TypeVar, Type

class _Foo(NamedTuple):
    my_list: List[int]


T = TypeVar('T', bound="Foo")


class Foo(_Foo):
    "A namedtuple defined as `_Foo(mylist)`, with a default value of `[]`"
    __slots__ = ()

    def __new__(cls: Type[T], mylist: Optional[List[int]] = None) -> T:
        mylist = [] if mylist is None else mylist
        return super().__new__(cls, mylist)  # type: ignore


f, g = Foo(), Foo()
print(isinstance(f, Foo))  # prints "True"
print(isinstance(f, _Foo))  # prints "True"
print(f.mylist is g.mylist)  # prints "False"
```

Run it through MyPy and the revealed type of `f` and `g` will be: `"Tuple[builtins.list[builtins.int], fallback=__main__.Foo]"`.

I'm not sure why I had to add the `# type: ignore` to get MyPy to stop complaining — if anybody can enlighten me on that, I'd be interested. Seems to work fine at runtime.

Comment: Great, thank you!
You could use `cls._field_defaults.items()` and `isinstance(value, Field)` with `value.default_factory()` to combine `NamedTuple` and `from dataclasses import field`.

Answer (score 7):

Use a dataclass instead of a named tuple. A dataclass allows a field to specify a default *factory* rather than a single default value.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Foo:
    my_list: List[int] = field(default_factory=list)
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: Updated to use the approach of Alex, because this works much better than my previous idea.

Here is a Alex's `Foo` class put into a decorator:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple, List, Callable, TypeVar, cast, Type
T = TypeVar('T')

def default_factory(**factory_kw: Callable) -> Callable[[Type[T]], Type[T]]:
    def wrapper(wcls:  Type[T]) -> Type[T]:
        def du_new(cls: Type[T], **kwargs) -> T:
            for key, factory in factory_kw.items():
                if key not in kwargs:
                    kwargs[key] = factory()
            return super(cls, cls).__new__(cls, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
        return type(f'{wcls.__name__}_', (wcls, ), {'__new__': du_new})
    return wrapper

@default_factory(my_list=list)
class Foo(NamedTuple):
    my_list: List[int] = []  # you still need to define the default argument

foo1 = Foo()
foo1.my_list.append(42)

foo2 = Foo()
print(foo2.my_list)  # prints []
#reveal_type(foo2) # prints Tuple[builtins.list[builtins.int], fallback=foo.Foo]
```

Comment: I love this idea, but I think there's a few small issues with it. If you enter this into the interactive REPL, then type `>>>Foo`, the output is `<class '__main__.Foo_'>`. Similarly, if you enter `Foo.__mro__`, the output is `(<class '__main__.Foo_'>, <class '__main__.Foo'>, <class 'tuple'>, <class 'object'>)`, and if you enter `Foo.__new__.__name__`, the output is `'du_new'`. I've edited my answer to combine our approaches with a solution that fixes these introspection problems!

Comment: My favourite thing about this is that we've basically created an "invisible" class, `_Foo`, which you can *only* find a reference to in the `__mro__` of `Foo`. It doesn't exist in the global namespace. Type `_Foo` into the REPL and you get a `NameError`. Deep, deep magic.

Comment: And this magic is only required, cause we can't directly overwrite __new__ in the NamedTuple directly. :-(

Comment: True, though that's just because it's using a metaclass, right? And the `NamedTuple` metaclass does so many other awesome things for us, so I think this is a small hardship to bear in the scheme of things.