# How to type annotate decorators for classes?

Tags: python, decorator, type-hinting, mypy, pyright

I have the following code:

```py
class Mixin:
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 1

def add_mixin(cls):
    class WithMixin(cls, Mixin):
        __name__ = cls.__name__
        __doc__ = cls.__doc__
    return WithMixin

@add_mixin
class B:
    def bar(self) -> int:
        return 2

b = B()
print(b.foo())
print(b.bar())
```

I understand, that in this particular case I can just write `B(Mixin)` and avoid the decorator, but in reality there's a lot of logic in `add_mixin`, which chooses/customizes the `Mixin` class (think `@dataclass`).

The code works the way you'd expect: prints 1 and 2. However, it blinds my `pyright` - I no longer can jump to `bar`, as `pyright` doesn't understand that `WithMixin` inherits from both `Mixin` and `B`.

Furthermore, `mypy` gets confused the other way:

```
mypy type_checking.py
type_checking.py:17: error: "B" has no attribute "foo"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I'm annotating the core of an existing library, so lists of `@overloads` or some outright magic is fine with me - I just want the annotation to be correct.

I would like some help with two things:

1. **How do I properly annotate `add_mixin`** (or rewrite it to have the same effect) so that `pyright` / `mypy` work correctly?
2. Is there a comprehensive resource on typing? Preferably something that explains the implementations of the `typing` module (which is confusing!) and the way type checkers use these annotations. I've read the [reference for typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), and both [PEP 483](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/) and [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), and I think I have a decent grasp on all the covariance/contravariance/bound types stuff. However, when there's a somehwat complicated case I haven't seen before (like here), I feel completely lost. Googling around mostly leads to the same reference-style or surface-level articles (or PEPs).

---

I went through quite a few failed attempts, the last one being:

```
from typing import *

class Mixin:
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 1

_T1 = TypeVar("_T1")
class WithMixin(Type[_T1], Mixin):
    ...


def add_mixin(cls: Type[_T1]) -> WithMixin[_T1]:
    return type(cls.__name__, (cls, Mixin), {})

@add_mixin
class B:
    def bar(self) -> int:
        return 2

b = B()
print(b.foo())
print(b.bar())
```

`pyright` gets confused at the `type(cls.__name__, (cls, Mixin), {})` line, while `mypy` says inheriting from `Type[_T1]` is not allowed (which it isn't, but I thought that the type checker might pick it up anyway).

Comment: Can we maybe see see a little more of the logic in `add_mixin` that's motivated you to go for this unusual design? `@dataclass` is special-cased by type-checkers, I think, and they're only able to special-case it because it's very predictable in the changes it will make to a class.

Comment: For python-typing resources, I can recommend the mypy docs https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html and Adam Johnson's blog, which has featured a lot of excellent typing-related posts recently https://adamj.eu

Comment: For one - `pydantic`'s `dataclass` doesn't work, which is how I stumbled onto this issue initially some time ago. I guess, it isn't special-cased the same way. A `@property` in the decorated class will not be discovered by a type checker.

In general, I feel like "parametrized mixin" basically means "decorator". I can forward parameters via `super().__init__`, but that will still turn into a typing nightmare, if, depending on these parameters, the class definition changes significantly (e.g., a parameter that regulates which magic functions should be supported by a class).

Comment: Usually my solution for this kind of thing would be to use `typing.cast` (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68699292/1399001), but this is so dynamic that I can't really see a solution unless you wrote your own mypy plugin

Comment: Pydantic does have a mypy plugin btw, which might help with that specific issue https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/mypy_plugin/

Comment: Yes, thanks. I found that `pyright` also has [some special case](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/specs/dataclass_transforms.md#applying-to-pydantic) support for `pydantic`.

Comment: This is kind of sad :( Typings done right improve the coding experience by so much but it feels so unpolished and unpythonic at times. I don't really understand why the second code example (or something similar, by defining atomic building blocks for typing and multiple-inheriting from them) wouldn't work - feels like the internal machinery is there.

Comment: I agree that there are still a lot of rough edges. I think you've got to remember how new these tools, and the `typing` module, still are. As for your second example — the issue is that the definition of the class can't be evaluated statically, only at runtime. Mypy can't handle dynamically generated classes except in special cases. In some ways what you're doing is very similar to a metaclass. See the documentation on metaclasses: "Mypy does not and cannot understand arbitrary metaclass code". https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/metaclasses.html