# Allow the deafult constructor to accept an instance and return it unchainged

Tags: python, python-3.x, default-constructor

I would like to allow my class constructor to accept an instance of this class and in that case to return this same instance instead of creating a new object.  Like what `tuple` does:

```
>>> t = (1, 2, 3)
>>> tuple(t) is t
True
```

I imagine I need to override the `__new__` method for this, and additionally take care of this special case in the `__init__` method.  Are there any recipes for this?

I would have preferred to completely skip `__init__` when the constructor is given a class instance that it is going to return unchanged, but I see no way.  I am also a bit suspicious about the triple use of `cls` in the line with `super`:

```
class C:
    @staticmethod
    def __new__(cls, x=None):
        if isinstance(x, cls):
            return x
        else:
            return super(cls, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, x=None):
        if x is self: return  # Can I just skip __init__ instead?
        self.x = x
```

(I know about `super()` without arguments, but I do not like [inconsistent](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/344377) [magic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19608134).)

After learning more about `super` and about MRO in Python, i've figure out that this code is not good.  For example, subclassing `C` results in

```
>>> class D(C): pass
>>> d = D(1)
......
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I am so terrified by `super()` without arguments that magically extracts its arguments from the (lexical or dynamic?) context, that rather than using it I've decided to add a "callback" to finalise the class definition:

```
class C2:
    @classmethod
    def finalise(this_cls_yes_this_one):
        @staticmethod
        def __new__(cls, x=None):
            if isinstance(x, cls):
                return x
            else:
                return super(this_cls_yes_this_one, cls).__new__(cls)

        this_cls_yes_this_one.__new__ = __new__

        del this_cls_yes_this_one.finalise

    def __init__(self, x=None):
        if x is self: return
        self.x = x

C2.finalise()
```

Comment: Consider that, for mutable values, this may give surprising results: `a1.val=1; a2=A(a1); a2.val=2; print(a1.val);` The users of your class might expect that the constructor generates a copy for mutable objects.

Comment: This would actually be the expected result. As i said, i want the constructor to return the same object. Moreover, my class instances are not intended for mutation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a metaclass. The `__init__` and `__new__` methods are called in `__call__` method of the metacalss whenever an instance is call. You can handle both by overriding the metaclasses `__call__` function.

```
class MyMetaClass(type):

    def __call__(cls, obj, *args, **kwargs):
        if (isinstance(obj, cls)):
            return obj
        else:
            self = cls.__new__(cls, obj, *args, **kwargs)
            cls.__init__(self, obj, *args, **kwargs)
            return self
            # Note: In order to be sure that you don't miss anything
            # It's better to do super().__call__(obj, *args, **kwargs) here

class A(metaclass=MyMetaClass):
    def __init__(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):
        self.val = obj
```

Demo:

```
a = A(10)
b = A(a)
c = A(40)
print(b is a)
print(a.val)
print(b.val)
print(c is a)
print(c.val)

# out:
True
10
10
False
40
```

Comment: Could the `else` clause of `MyMetaClass.__call__` be: `else: return super().__call__(obj, *args, **kwargs)` ?

Comment: Would it be possible to have a link to Python's documentation to confirm that there is nothing else to take care of in `__cal__` of a class?

Comment: @Alexey I'm not sure but for the peace of mind as Rob said you should use `super()`.

Comment: @Kasramvd - sorry, I didn't read the question closely enough. Never mind.