# How both ignore type check and obey line <80 chars

Tags: python, pep8, namedtuple, mypy

I have this data type that just groups related data.  It should be a struct-like thing, so I opted for a `namedtuple`.

```
ConfigOption = namedtuple('ConfigOption', 'one two animal vehicle fairytale')
```

On the other hand, `namedtuple` has no defaults, so I reside to a hack proposed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18348004/6610).

```
ConfigOption.__new__.__defaults__ = (1, 2, "White Horse", "Pumpkin", "Cinderella")
```

Obviously, this makes the type check fail: `error: "Callable[[Type[NT], Any, Any, Any, Any, Any], NT]" has no attribute "__defaults__"`

Since I'm well aware this is a hack, I tell the type checker so using an inline comment `# type: disable`:

```
ConfigOption.__new__.__defaults__ = (1, 2, "White Horse", "Pumpkin", "Cinderella")  # type: disable
```

At this time... the line becomes too long.  I have *no* idea how to break this line so that it is syntactically correct and at the same time make the type checker skip it:

```
# the ignore is on the wrong line
ConfigOption.__new__.__defaults__ = \
    (1, 2, "White Horse", "Pumpkin", "Cinderella")  # type: ignore

# unexpected indentation
ConfigOption.__new__.__defaults__ =  # type: ignore
    (1, 2, "White Horse", "Pumpkin", "Cinderella")
```

So is there a way to exclude a single line from type checking, or to format this long line, so that both the type check is skipped, and the line length is pep-8 compliant?

Comment: Python >= 3.7 has defaults for namedtuples. https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what's wrong with:

```
option_defaults = (1, 2, "White Horse", "Pumpkin", "Cinderella")
ConfigOption.__new__.__defaults__ = option_defaults  # type: ignore
```

Comment: apart from pep-8 telling me to use OPTION_DEFAULTS, nothing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Enum seems to follow the constraints you require, and is quite concise.

You can use the [Functional API](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html#functional-api), which itself says the `semantics resemble namedtuple`

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> Enum('ConfigOption', 'one two animal vehicle fairytale')
<enum 'ConfigOption'>
>>> ConfigOption = Enum('ConfigOption', 'one two animal vehicle fairytale')
>>> [c for c in ConfigOption]
[<ConfigOption.one: 1>, <ConfigOption.two: 2>, <ConfigOption.animal: 3>, <ConfigOption.vehicle: 4>, <ConfigOption.fairytale: 5>]
```